# How to get Microsoft CRM for Development Purposes?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am a recent graduate, who has done some work experience at a company developing/designing Microsoft Dynamics CRM Solutions. I have moved on from there and have no official ties anymore. However, I do see the future in this product and I would like to keep developing solutions and increasing my development knowledge of Microsoft Dynamics CRM.

Taking into account the above and that I have a job in a different IT area. As well as the fact that I am determined to start this from scratch... What are my options?

My intentions for the future(1-3 yrs) is to develop Microsoft CRM 2013 Solutions and hopefully sell to local small businesses.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to get an online subscription. Your solution's code should be 100% compatible with the new CRM APIs in the SDK. Running everything from an online CRM solution would ensure it will work. This will also ensure that when the next version is released, you will be ready for it.

Unless Microsoft changes their licensing, this might be your only reasonably priced choice.

Comment: -Could you provide a link for purchasing? Correct me if im wrong the online version will still allow me to develop CRM solutions and not just customising and configuring it.

Comment: [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-purchase-support.aspx) is the link. You can also try it free for a limited time. Any solution you create can be uploaded to your own CRM instance. Any plugins will be placed in a Sandbox. this is how they allow 3rd party developers, like yourself, upload solutions into their cloud. Also, you may be interested in becoming a CRM Microsoft Partner in the future. This is another way to generate customers and profit from your development. Hope this answers your questions.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN subscription or using trial subscription on CRM Online instance or using trial key:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40341

Or if you want to be a startup, you might be eligible for BizSpark subscription:
http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/

Answer (score 0):

Try the Demo Builder:

http://demobuilder.cloudapp.net/unauthenticated-home/#

It's a Wizard base tool that will guide you through the process of setting up an online demo environment.

There are a bunch of templates that you can select from that will give you a good idea of the different scenarios where CRM can be deployed.

Comment: Don't think this is relevant, im looking for a solution where i can have access to dynamics crm to develop solutions.

Comment: That's exactly what it is. Did you even take a look at the link??  It will set up a demo environment for you online where you can build your solutions.

Comment: Ok, Can i develop SSRS reports?

Comment: Yes, you can develop SSRS reports using FetchXML and import them into CRM. Note, you will need to use FetchXML as CRM online does not expose the database directly.